# ValueError when using Strptime

Tags: python, strptime, valueerror

I am trying to extract the month, hour and day of the week from `starttime`.

```
City: NYC
OrderedDict([('tripduration', '839'),
             ('starttime', '1/1/2016 00:09:55'),
             ('stoptime', '1/1/2016 00:23:54'),
             ('start station id', '532'),
             ('start station name', 'S 5 Pl & S 4 St'),
             ('start station latitude', '40.710451'),
             ('start station longitude', '-73.960876'),
             ('end station id', '401'),
             ('end station name', 'Allen St & Rivington St'),
             ('end station latitude', '40.72019576'),
             ('end station longitude', '-73.98997825'),
             ('bikeid', '17109'),
             ('usertype', 'Customer'),
             ('birth year', ''),
             ('gender', '0')])
datum_n_m = example_trips['NYC'][datetime.strptime('starttime','%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')]
```

> ValueError: time data 'starttime' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'

Answer (score 1):

First, let's make a [mcve]

```
# you do need to import stuff
from datetime import datetime

# the ordered dict is irrelevant, so get rid of it

# this reproduces the error
print (datetime.strptime('starttime','%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

This reproduces

> builtins.ValueError: time data 'starttime' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'

That is because the string "starttime" is not a time in that format. It is just a couple of letters. If you had made a basic [mcve] you would have solved your own problem. Basic debugging :)

Maybe you meant something like:

```
start_time_as_string = example_trips['NYC']['starttime']
datum_n_m = datetime.strptime( start_time_as_string )
```